# Guest Session Default Settings

Tags: release-loki, default

How to change the default settings guest session opens with? Everytime someone has to use the guest session I have to configure the correct screen resolution, add apps to the dock, etc. All the changes are lost after log out, so I have to set everything up manually again.

Answer (score 1):

"Using a special user account for setting the guest preferences is the most convenient way to customize the guest session feature. Please follow these steps:

Add a new user account with the username guest-prefs.

Log in to guest-prefs and change things to what you want your guests encounter at startup.

Open a terminal window and create a symbolic link to the home directory of guest-prefs:

sudo mkdir /etc/guest-session
sudo ln -s /home/guest-prefs /etc/guest-session/skel
Now, when you launch a guest session, it will have the same preferences as you set for guest-prefs.

Notes:

In this tutorial we use the name guest-prefs, but you can give the special purpose user some other username.

You may prefer to hide guest-prefs from the login screen and the system menu. Hopefully that will be easy to accomplish when https://launchpad.net/bugs/857651 has been fixed."

Source - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession